# Storing long text-based paragraphs or headings in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering about how to store long text-based html elements like `<p>, <h1>, <h2>, <h3>` etc. in React.js in a semantically good way. By studying the react.js documentation I understood that we can store our elements in react in variables.

```
const title = <h2>Branding changed the game in my life, and I'm excited for it to do the same for you, too. </h2>;
```

```
<div className="flex-container">
   <h2>{title}</h2>
   <p>{me}</p>
</div>
```

What I presented above can be considered as correct? Is there a more elegant way to write the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have above will render an `h2` within an `h2`. Also this is a feature of JSX, not necessarily React itself. I would suggest storing the strings themselves in variables, independent of any markup.

You have to ask yourself why you’re doing that in the first place. The most semantic thing would be to write out everything as JSX, without abstracting to variables unless you need to.

Comment: *"The most semantic thing"* semantics is about what is rendered in DOM. The whole point of React is to be able to use the power of JavaScript while you're creating it

Comment: @TJ I agree with you

Comment: I meant to say more semantic, more so from a human readability point of view. Using the power of JavaScript you can abstract each part of JSX to variables that contain markup etc, and you’d be left with a list of variables creating some meta-language that only you know the rules to.

Comment: @ParthianShotgun Like I said in the other comment ReactJS precisely recommends splitting the code to be more readable ("We split JSX over multiple lines for readability." -> reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not correct, because your are putting an h2 inside another h2. Also "me" is not defined.

In a typical application, "title" and "me" would be passed in as pops, so that the component you are writing remains reusable.

```
<div className="flex-container">
   <h2>{props.title}</h2>
   <p>{props.me}</p>
</div>
```

Another component higher in the hierarchy could define

```
const title = "Branding changed the game in my life, and I'm excited for it to do the same for you, too.";
const me = "Some text";
```

And pass them as props to your reusable component

```
<MyComponent title={title} me={me} />
```

This is just a simple example. Normally these texts would come from data structures like arrays, etc.

Answer (score 0):

All these ways are corrects

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

const shortText = "This is a short text";

const shortTextBis = <p>This is a short text</p>;

const shortTextQuote = `I'm happy`;

const longText =
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam lorem in sodales cursus. Vivamus non quam vitae ipsum lacinia volutpat. Cras nec placerat ante. Nullam vitae leo ultrices, auctor sem ut, ullamcorper nunc. Mauris in massa orci. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus fermentum augue vel eros tempor, vitae pulvinar dolor sagittis.";

const textH2 = <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam lorem in sodales cursus. Vivamus non quam vitae ipsum lacinia volutpat.</h2>;

const textH2Bis = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam lorem in sodales cursus. Vivamus non quam vitae ipsum lacinia volutpat.'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{shortText}</p>
      {shortTextBis}
      <p>{shortTextQuote}</p>
      <p>{longText}</p>
      {textH2}
      <h2>{textH2Bis}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nxf2th?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: While they may all be ‘correct’, its often better to consider semantics and legibility first. I would say that the first consideration would be to put the string in the JSX as is, without resorting to early abstraction.

Comment: @ParthianShotgun "We split JSX over multiple lines for readability." -> https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: This is referring to the formatting of the JSX itself, its split over multiple lines because its easier to read, just like regular old HTML

Comment: @ParthianShotgun He will choose according to the expected result and his tastes in terms of readability